# Equivalent of match function but with near-equality option?

Tags: r, match

I'm using the data.table capabilities to use `match` to find all identical rows in two arrays of floats.
Simple example:

```
common_rows <- match( data.frame(t(mat_one)) , data.frame(t(mat_two)))
```

I could take the obvious precaution of first rounding `mat_one` and `mat_two` to common precision, but that requires first determining the general magnitudes of the values and calculating an appropriate precision (number of digits) to apply (not difficult either, just have to grab the integer part of `log10(x)` and juggle that a bit).  What I'd like would be the equivalent of `base::match` but with an argument that says "do approxequal" ).

The important point here is that I want to get the indices of the matches, rather than plowing through various  `compare` functions and then digging into the matrices to locate the rows of interest.
Is there a simpler,or more accurate, way to do this other than pre-rounding the data?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this. Using `outer` to calculate distance and than get `which.min` per row.

```
i <- abs(outer(x, y, "-"))
apply(i, 1, which.min)
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Or in case `outer` uses to much memory:

```
sapply(x, function(x) which.min(abs(x-y)))
```

Data:

```
x <- 1:4
y <- c(1,2,3.000000001,4)
```

Comment: Not sure... I want the entire rows to match up.  so  `c(1,2,3,4)`  matches .  `c(1,2,3,4)` , but doesn't match `c(1,2,3.000000001,4)` ,  while avoiding an erroneous mismatch due to floating point precision limit ( 3.0  got turned into   3.0+1e-16 by some floating point operation)